# The form of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a countable collection of pairwise disjoint subsets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove a statement in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664183/the-%CF%83-algebra-generated-by-a-countable-collection-of-pairwise-disjoint-sets-pro), i.e.,

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a countable collection of pairwise disjoint subsets of $X$ such that $\emptyset \in \mathcal A$. Then
> $$
> \sigma (\mathcal A) = \left \{ \cup_{i \in J} A_i,  X \setminus (\cup_{i \in J} A_i)  \,\middle\vert\, J \subset I  \right\}.
> $$

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**Proof:** First, we need a simple lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a countable partition of $X$ such that $\emptyset \in \mathcal A$. Then
> $$
> \sigma (\mathcal A) = \mathcal B:= \left \{ \cup_{i \in J} A_i  \,\middle\vert\, J \subset I  \right\}.
> $$
>
> *Proof:* It's clear that any $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal A$ will contain $\mathcal B$. It remains to prove that $\mathcal B$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra. Clearly, $\mathcal B$ is closed under countable union. Let's prove that it is closed under complement. Let $A := \cup_{i \in J} A_i$ with $J \subset I$. Then $A^c = \bigcup_{i \in J'} A_i \in \mathcal B$ with $J' =I \setminus J$.

Now we come back to the original theorem. Let $B:= X \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$. Then
$$
\sigma (\mathcal A) = \sigma (\mathcal A \cup \{B\}).
$$

Clearly, $\mathcal A \cup \{B\}$ is a countable partition of $X$. By our **Lemma**,
$$
\sigma (\mathcal A) =  \left \{ \cup_{i \in J} A_i, B \cup (\cup_{i \in J} A_i)  \,\middle\vert\, J \subset I  \right\}.
$$

Notice that
$$
B \cup (\cup_{i \in J} A_i)   = X \setminus (\cup_{i \in J'} A_i),
$$
with $J' = I \setminus J$. This completes the proof.