# The form of the conditional expectation when the $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $\mathcal A = (A_n, n \in \mathbb N)$ be a sequence of *pairwise disjoint* sets in $\mathcal F$. Let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be an integrable random variable.  I'm trying to solve *Exercise 2* in [this](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Elalley/Courses/385/ConditionalExpectation.pdf) note, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $I := \{n \in \mathbb N : \mathbb P[A_n]>0\}$. Then
> $$
> \mathbb E[X | \sigma(\mathcal A)] = \sum_{n \in I} \frac{\mathbb E[X1_{A_n}]}{\mathbb P[A_n]} 1_{A_n}.
> $$

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** We need the following lemma to characterize $\sigma(\mathcal A)$.

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555620/the-form-of-a-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-countable-collection-of-pairwise-d) Let $\mathcal A = (A_n, n \in \mathbb N)$ be a sequence of *pairwise disjoint* subsets of $\Omega$. Then
> $$
> \sigma (\mathcal A) = \bigg \{ \emptyset,\bigcup_{n \in J} A_n,  X \setminus \bigg ( \bigcup_{n \in J} A_i \bigg)  : J \subset \mathbb N  \bigg\}.
> $$

Let $Z := \sum_{n \in I} \frac{\mathbb E[X1_{A_n}]}{\mathbb P[A_n]} 1_{A_n}$. Then $Z$ is $\sigma(\mathcal A)$-measurable. We need to prove that $\mathbb E [Z1_A] = \mathbb E[X1_A]$ for all $A \in \sigma(\mathcal A)$. Notice that $\mathbb E [Z] = \mathbb E[X]$. By our **Lemma** and the linearity of integral,  it suffices to prove that $\mathbb E [Z 1_{A_n}] = \mathbb E[X 1_{A_n}]$ for all $n \in I$. This is however trivially true. This completes the proof.

Comment: Your proof is correct. But not all countably generated $\sigma-$ algebras are generated by a disjoint sequence, so the title misleading.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your verification! Tittle edited.